# Update a table automatically date and time

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a table (mysql) similar to this:

```
id          int,
deadline    timestamp,
state       int
```

And state could be 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. 1: Open, 2: Pending, 3: Approved, 4: Closed, etc.

Deadline has a date and time and when it is reached the state should changed. For instance, if I have insert the following record:

insert into table (id, deadline, state) values(1, '2014-08-21 2:05:13', 1); (1 means Open).

When the deadline is reached state should be 2 (Pending) automatically.

How could I do this?

I thought of:

- Creating a process which should be executed once per second to update the table but in my opinion, it would be heavy (cron). In addition, my hosting provider doesn't support it.
- A trigger but it's not possible because it should be updated when the deadline is reached and not when I insert or update or delete the table.
- Handling the different states from my php code. Any time the state is requested but I work with the state from a lot of places inside my code and it would be complex and difficult to keep.

If you have any idea please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need once per second? Do you really need the level of precision necessary for aircraft navigation or monitoring drip feeds in a hospital?

Comment: Why not simply check the state and timestamp on read, and update at that point?

Comment: Are you actually printing any of that info on screen? If so, you can run an `if` statement to check if the state is past due. If it is, change the state.

Comment: If you have rights to use create Scheduled Events in MySQL, that's an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a View that uses a case statement to make your "state" column a 2 if it's 1 and expired, and then just query that View instead of the table directly.  Then update the table periodically by some other method, such as a trigger that updates the whole table (although that'd be random) . . .

Or you could make stored routines that access the table instead of writing your query in your application code, and that stored routine could update your "state" as need be.

Comment: I'm going to handle the conditions on my code and update the table once a day with a process. Thanks

Comment: Don't do what Willy says at home, kids. It's bad for your health.

Comment: you're right. What happened was that I didn't know what a case statement was, I was researching and I think is much better than handle conditions on the code. It's easier, thanks.